# Get dynamic id of element in each block in rails with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am explainig my problem in a simple example. I am building a recipe app. In my show partial which is loaded via AJAX I do the following:

**_show.html.erb**

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="ingredient-<%= ingredient.id %>">
    <div id="amount-<%= ingredient.id %>"><%= ingredient.amount %></div>
    <%= ingredient.unit.unit_name %>
    <%= ingredient.ingredient_name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me a list like:

- 250 g Cheese
- 1 l Milk
- etc.

What I want to do now (just in my example) is to replace each amount value with the phrase "Hi, it's me!". Therefore I thought I could use the following jquery (I am not using Turbolinks) in my partial to get the dynamic id from the each block:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#amount-<%= ingredient.id %>').html("Hi, it's me!");
});
```

I expect the list to be:

- Hi it's me! g Cheese
- Hi it's me! l Milk
- etc.

However, it does not work and I don't understand what am I doing wrong? If I use a static id or a static class it works. However (for some calculations I want to perform with each amount), I need it dynamic based on `<%= ingredient.id %>`.

Comment: Where do you put your second snippet (the one starting with `$( document ).ready`? Do you really have `<%= ingredient-id %>`? Because it makes no sense, I think you meant `<%= ingredient.id %>`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. That was a typo. I corrected it in my posting. Still it does not work. It put the jquery in my partial in a <script> tag. However, if I just use "amount" without <%= ingredient.id %> as a class it works. But then it's not indiviual anymore.

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my first question?

Comment: Ok maybe I don't understand your question but, as I said, I put the jquery in the partial (_show.html.erb) in a <script> tag. I put it directly in the html and not in a separate file in the asset pipeline because the id gets loaded dynamically.

Comment: Ok now I think I understand your question: I did not put the second snippet inside the each do loop. Updated my answer.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: True. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my error. Stupid mistake though. I have to put the jquery part inside the each do block. Otherwise, of course, <%= ingredient.id %> is not defined.

Solution looks now like this:

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="ingredient-<%= ingredient.id %>">
    <div id="amount-<%= ingredient.id %>"><%= ingredient.amount %></div>
    <%= ingredient.unit.unit_name %>
    <%= ingredient.ingredient_name %>
  </div>

  <script>
    $('#amount-<%= ingredient.id %>').html("Hi, it's me!");
  </script>

<% end %>
```